# Is it possible to trigger Informatica workflow using a data in database table?

Tags: informatica

I am a newbie in ETL and will be using Informatica soon for one of the requirements we have.

The requirement is that Informatica needs to monitor a table in Oracle for certain "trigger data" and as soon as that data is available in that table, Informatica should start executing steps in its workflow.

Is it possible to do this? If yes, could someone please point me to a link/document where this is explained.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible (checked in PowerCenter 9.5.1).

The `Event-Wait` task supports only two types of events:

- predefined events (the task instructs the Integration Service to wait for the specified indicator file to appear before continuing),
- user-defined events (the event is triggered by an `Event-Raise` task somewhere in the workflow).

Comment: I'd add that `Event-Wait` cannot be be used to `trigger` the workflow. The mechanics behind it is that the workflow has to be `running` already and then it waits for some event. The workflow will not get executed by the event.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible and you will be needing a script that can be created with following steps.

```
--create a shell script that checks if data is present in table on not you can use this just by taking count of the table
--if count is grater than create an empty file say DUMMY.txt (by using touch command) at a specified path.

--in you Informatica scheduling either by scheduler or by script check every 5 mins if file is present.

--if file is present call you Informatica workflow and delete the DUMMY file.

--once workflow is completed start the process again.
```